# chrome css transition flicker with paperfold adaption

Tags: css, transform, css-transitions

I'm trying to adapt the recently popular paperfold animation... basically extending it by an element at the very bottom which has no perspective and just moves unskewed.

http://jsfiddle.net/nicib83/dhrxU/1/

to exclude the bottom panel, comment out line 22

```
$(existing[existing.length-1]).append($('<div class="panel panel-bottom"></div>'));
```

however in chrome I have a white flickering which is a result of the background-colored bottom panel.

i'm really trying to understand the reason why to bottom panel seems to appear in between above

thx

Comment: funny, when i adjust the bottom layer degree to 89.999° or 90.001° its gone